# NSJSONWriter dataWithRootObject:options:error:

Tags: ios, json

[image: error description]

This is the error description.

And how can I solve this?

Comment: you may add some more information about your question

Comment: put the code which you have try..

Comment: if (dict) {
            NSData *pushData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dict options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:nil];
            self.args = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:pushData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        }